# How to curl post data with special characters @ and <

Tags: json, curl, http-post

I am using slack app to send message to a slack channel by using incoming webhook. And I have created a bat file and use curl to post message.
The thing is if I want to mention someone, I need `<@username>` in the post data.

The post request looks like this

`Content-Type: application/json`

`POST https://hooks.slack.com/services/token?{"text":"<@username>This is a test message"}`

with curl, I have

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "https://hooks.slack.com/services/token" -d "{\"text\":\"<@username>This is a test message\"}"`

The error message I got is

> 0<@username 1>This
>   The system cannot find the file specified

I realized that `@username` symbol makes curl load data from given file "username"

I tried some suggestion which I can find, e.g. to encode the post data
`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "https://hooks.slack.com/services/token" -d "{\"text\":\"%3C%40username%3EThis is a test message\"}"`

I got the message

> C0usernameEThis is a test message

Does anyone can help me with this? Otherwise I might give up with curl and try something else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html:

> `--data-raw`: (HTTP) This posts data similarly to -d, --data but without the special interpretation of the @ character.

Comment: strange, it doesn't work as it should. the error message told me it's still trying to load file.